# How I do obtain the elements in a row from an expression

Tags: get, grep

I want to figure out how to obtain all the elements from an entire row from a matrix when I'm given an element in a matrix.

In my case, I have a matrix that's already a dataset, with a set amount of rows and columns. The Columns are categories defining the elements for each row.

As an illustration:

> colnames(data.set) 
>   "GOID" "TERM" "ONTOLOGY" "DEFINITION"

I was given an element "response to heat", which is under "TERM" colname, 
and I have to find the responding element in the "GOID" colnam.

Comment: `grep "element" <file>`?

Comment: colnames(data.set)
"GOID"       "TERM"       "ONTOLOGY"   "DEFINITION"

I was given an element "response to heat", which is under "TERM" colname, and I have to find the "GOID"

Comment: Please, add this information to your question as an example: make a sample table with the columns and rows you have, point out the element you've been given, and the result you'd like to have. You're to get a better answer this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more complete example for your question would be something like:

```
GOID | TERM | ONTOLOGY | DEFINITION
 x1  |  x2  |    x3    |     x4
 y1  |  y2  |    y3    |     y4
 z1  |  z2  |    z3    |     z4
 ..  |  ..  |    ..    |     ..
```

Considering `y2` to be `response to heat`, to retrieve the value `y1`, you can simply use `grep` and `cut/awk/argument expansion/sed/...`. It all depends on your separator.

If the separator, as in your example, are whitespaces, you may do:

```
GOID TERM ONTOLOGY DEFINITION
x1 x2 x3 x4
y1 y2 y3 y4
z1 z2 z3 z4
.. .. .. ..

grep "y2" <file> | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Output:

```
y1
```

Comment: @user2105555 Please, if this answer helped you, accept it as a valid answer, pressing the tick mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: Now how would I do this using grep in R?

Comment: @user2105555 I didn't even know one could use `grep` in `R`! (: If this is your question, you must either edit this one, or open a new one, adding appropriate tags, like `R`. Anyway, you don't really have to do it *inside* `R`, you can first treat your text, and then use it as input for any `R` script you have.

Comment: Good point! Regardless, I greatly appreciate your prompt and helpful response!